# I have a couple general functionality questions regarding Scheduled Triggered Flows

Tags: visual-workflow

In a scheduled flow, you can select an object with filter criteria in the trigger, or you could also not choose an object and use a Get Records element with the same object and criteria. Is there a huge difference between the two?

My part 2 to this question, if you choose an object within the initial trigger, it says that each record found is entered into a batch, which then each record would go through an instance of the flow. In that same flow, would a loop of those same object records then be redundant? For example we are getting contacts records that have a value in a specific field. We can put that criteria in the trigger, so then we wouldn't need a loop that is going through each contact record because they are already in a batch? Is there a preference for a way to do this?

I don't know if that last question makes sense, I try and expound if need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A scheduled flow with entry conditions will work like an Apex batchable

Example: You have 50,000 Contacts, 10,000 of which are of recordtype B2B

If the flow's entry conditions say to retrieve all Contacts of recordtype B2B then the following happens:

- 10,000/200 = 50 transactions start (serially)
- Each transaction consists of 200 Flow Interviews
- Each Flow Interview only needs logic to think about a single Contact
- Best-positioned to not exceed limits

If you don't have any Flow entry condition and instead do a Get Records for the B2B Contacts, you get

- One transaction
- One Flow Interview
- High likelihood you exhaust some limit like CPU
- You have to implement a loop over 10,000 records
- Will fail for sure if you retrieve 50000+ records